# DRBD service vs drbdadm

Tags: drbd

DRBD v9.17 (kernel v9.1.4)

I'm trying to understand the typical roles of `drbd` when run as a service vs manually with the `drbdadm` tool which seems newer than some of the walkthroughs I'm seeing online.

When should the service be used vs the `drbdadm` tool and where does `pacemaker` fit in regarding control of `drbd`'s failover?

I have created a resource manually using `drbdadm` and have it up and now showing `UPToDate` with the status command on both nodes. I need to figure out how to get that implemented in pacemaker for failover and I just think I'm missing the big picture here - The addition of the resource in pacemaker seems a bit more complicated than that of a floating IP...  Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drbdadm` has been around since the beginning so it's not newer than any tutorials.

The service will load the DRBD kernel module and bring up all the DRBD devices on a node (like `drbdadm up all` would) on boot when enabled, but will not attempt to promote it to Primary and cannot mount a device. That is what Pacemaker is often used for when combined with DRBD, promoting a DRBD node to Primary, and then starting services with the DRBD Primary.

DRBD 9.x does have an auto-promote feature enabled by default, so if you attempt to mount (or otherwise access) the device without promoting it to Primary first and no other node is currently Primary, it will auto-promote itself to Primary so it can be accessed.

Pacemaker is a cluster resource manager, so it's job is to start/stop/monitor services across a series of nodes and ensure correct ordering and location of those resources. DRBD is controlled as a "multi-state" (or `ms`) clone resource in Pacemaker, which is basically a clone set with multiple states (Primary and Secondary in DRBD's case, but this could be Master and Standby in a Database clone set).

Example snippet of a DRBD resource named `r0` configured in a 2-node Pacemaker cluster would look like this:

```
primitive p_drbd_r0 ocf:linbit:drbd \
    params drbd_resource=r0 \
    op start interval=0s timeout=240 \
    op promote interval=0s timeout=90 \
    op demote interval=0s timeout=90 \
    op stop interval=0s timeout=100 \
    op monitor interval=29 role=Master \
    op monitor interval=31 role=Slave
ms ms_drbd_r0 p_drbd_r0 \
    meta master-max=1 master-node-max=1 \
    notify=true clone-max=2 clone-node-max=1
```

If you wanted to manage mounting a filesystem on `r0`, you'd need to add the filesystem resource and constraints that tie it to the Primary DRBD node:

```
primitive p_fs_drbd Filesystem \
    params device="/dev/drbd0" directory="/drbd" \
    fstype=xfs options="noatime,nodiratime" \
    op start interval=0 timeout=60s \
    op stop interval=0 timeout=60s \
    op monitor interval=20 timeout=40s
colocation cl_fs-with-ms_drbd_r0 inf: p_fs_drbd:Started ms_drbd_r0:Master
order o_ms_drbd_r0-before-fs ms_drbd_r0:promote p_fs_drbd:start
```

You have to create the filesystem on the DRBD device before you manage it in Pacemaker.

DRBD's job is to replicate a block device between nodes.